# MS Project 2013 - Project Add-in or App for Office?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ms-project, office-2013, ms-project-server-2013

I would like to extend MS Project Professional 2013 functionality by providing set of own scheduling algorithms. Which approach would be better? To implement it in Project add-in or in app for office?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to use Sharepoint? What do you mean by "in app for office"?